# how to save a command in bash history without executing it programmatically?

Tags: bash, docker, command-history

I have a docker container and every time I build and start it, I want just to press <kbd>UP</kbd> for choosing a predefined command.

What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ echo "<yourcommand>" >> ~/.bash_history
```

or set up an alias in your `.bashrc` / `.bash_aliases`

`alias s='<yourcommand(s)>'` so every time you input `s` and hit enter it executes your commands.

Comment: Thx, I added your first suggestion in my Dockerfile and it works like a charm. It's so simple :)

Comment: For anyone who wants to keep the command out of the Dockerfile (because you only use it for dev, etc.), you can use `bash -c` to create the history / add the alias as shown in the answer. e.g., `docker run -it ubuntu bash -c 'echo "<yourcommand>" >> ~/.bash_history && bash'`

Answer (score 0):

I do:
: some_command

Then edit off the colon when I recall it in history. Colon is the null command. It used to be the way to comment things out before the hash became the comment character